# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help with my stored procedure, I kept getting this Error, but I can't find the real error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

My code:

```
    DECLARE @Batch_Num_For_Sending BIGINT;
DECLARE @IPLocal NVARCHAR(15);

SET @IPLocal = (
        SELECT Local_IPAddress
        FROM [RFIDSync].[dbo].[RFID_LinkSetup]
        WHERE Link_ID = 1
        );

DECLARE @IPMain NVARCHAR(15);

SET @IPMain = (
        SELECT Main_IPAddress
        FROM [RFIDSync].[dbo].[RFID_LinkSetup]
        WHERE Link_ID = 1
        );

DECLARE @LocationProj NVARCHAR(50);

SET @LocationProj = 'Test_Project';
SET @Batch_Num_For_Sending = (
        SELECT MIN(Batch_Id)
        FROM [db].[dbo].[LOCALBATCH]
        WHERE Batch_Status = 0
        )

SELECT @Batch_Num_For_Sending

EXEC (
        '
        SELECT Sync_Batch_Num FROM OPENQUERY([' + @IPMain + '\SQLEXPRESS], ''SELECT Sync_Batch_Num
            FROM [db].[dbo].[SYNCBATCH] WHERE [Location] = ''''' + @LocationProj + '''''
            '')
            WHERE Sync_Batch_Num = ' + @Batch_Num_For_Sending + '
        '
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution should add the missing `'` :

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Sync_Batch_Num FROM OPENQUERY([' + @IPMain + '\SQLEXPRESS], ''SELECT Sync_Batch_Num
                FROM [db].[dbo].[SYNCBATCH] WHERE [Location] = ''''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @LocationProj) + ''''''')
                WHERE Sync_Batch_Num = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @Batch_Num_For_Sending) + '';

    PRINT @SQL

    EXEC (@SQL)
```

Try printing the result query next time to detect the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your query may be ending up with different quotation marks than it is required.
Assign the dynamic sql to a variable first and see it output before passing it on to the EXEC() statement.

try the below one

```
DECLARE @Batch_Num_For_Sending bigint;
DECLARE @IPLocal nvarchar(15);
SET @IPLocal = (SELECT Local_IPAddress FROM [RFIDSync].[dbo].[RFID_LinkSetup] WHERE Link_ID = 1);
DECLARE @IPMain nvarchar(15);
SET @IPMain = (SELECT Main_IPAddress FROM [RFIDSync].[dbo].[RFID_LinkSetup] WHERE Link_ID = 1);
DECLARE @LocationProj nvarchar(50); SET @LocationProj = 'Test_Project';

DECLARE @SQ VARCHAR(4) = ''''
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @Batch_Num_For_Sending = (SELECT MIN(Batch_Id) FROM [db].[dbo].[LOCALBATCH] WHERE Batch_Status = 0)
SELECT @Batch_Num_For_Sending

SET @SQL = 'SELECT Sync_Batch_Num FROM OPENQUERY(['+@IPMain+'\SQLEXPRESS],' + @SQ + 'SELECT Sync_Batch_Num
        FROM [db].[dbo].[SYNCBATCH] WHERE [Location] =' + @SQ + @LocationProj+@SQ + ')
        WHERE Sync_Batch_Num = '+CAST(@Batch_Num_For_Sending AS VARCHAR)


EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Now I got this Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 15
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: @Kanyemon Do a `CAST(@Batch_Num_For_Sending AS VARCHAR)`